# Find a locator from an element in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Ok want to write a testmonkey for our web-application. This monkey should `log` in and randomly start entering values and clicking `webelements`.

So far, I have been able to log in, find the `webelements` (filter them) and then select one at random and Click it. I run into the `StaleElementReferenceException` after a random number of clicks though. All the solutions for this I was able to find suggest I wait for the element, or I find it again. Unfortunately I do not have a locator or path for the element, I only have the element itself.

My code looks like this:

```
public void Start()
{
    List<IWebElement> elements = _seleniumAdapter.AllElementsOnPage();
    Debug.WriteLine("Elementcount: " + elements.Count);
    IWebElement element = elements[_random.Next(elements.Count)];

    Debug.WriteLine(element.TagName + "," + element.Text);

    element.Click();
    if (element.GetAttribute("type").Contains("text"))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("text!");
        element.SendKeys(randomLetter());
    }
    Start();

}
```

Is there any way I can get around the `StaleElementReference`? AllElementsOnPage finds the elements `By.CssSelector("*")` and then filters the list before returning it, so that I only have clickable elements left.

Elements in our app do not have an id most of the time, so I can not use that. Nor have I been able to find any attribute that I can use as a unique selector.

I am stumped.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a very feasible way to do that. The css selctor will return you TONS of elements depending on the size of the page inluding **hidden** elements. Remember selenium won't be able to interact with hidden elements. There will be some elements that are not clickable for sure. And `Dom` refresh is the problem you are facing I ugess right now

Comment: Th AllElementsOnPage returns a filtered list. Hidden elements and stuff that can not be interacted with is filtered out, so that I remain with a short list of clickable and testable stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the index which _random.Next has generated for you in a variable. For Example i.

Then make changes in your code to catch the StaleElementReferenceException. In Catch block you can again populate your list and find the element with the same index which _random.Next has generated for you. 
Try to click it again in the catch block. If it is still cannot be clicked , catch it again in the second catch block and log the attributes of this element and move on to next elements. Afterwards you can inspect that what was actually wrong with this element. See the the changed code below.

```
   public void Start()
    {
        List<IWebElement> elements = _seleniumAdapter.AllElementsOnPage();
        Debug.WriteLine("Elementcount: " + elements.Count);
        int i = _random.Next(elements.Count);
        IWebElement element = elements[i];

        Debug.WriteLine(element.TagName + "," + element.Text);
        try
        {
        element.Click();
        }
        catch(StaleElementReferenceException ex)
        {
           elements = _seleniumAdapter.AllElementsOnPage();
           element = elements[i];
           element.Click()

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            element = null;
        }
        if(element != null)
       {
        if (element.GetAttribute("type").Contains("text"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("text!");
            element.SendKeys(randomLetter());
        }
        Start();
       }

    }
```

This approach is performance intensive, but it will get things done . I hope.